# How come Tvasta did a Yajna to kill Indra by praising Indra Himself?

Tags: rig-veda, indra, yajna

In Rigveda, Tvashta performed a Yajna to kill Indra after he got to know that his son Visvaroopa was killed by Indra. This yajna ensued birth of demon Vritra.

In Yajna a sacrificer recites some verse from Rigveda to please a deity. Since most of the verses are dedicated to **Indra**, I assume he pleased Indra to kill **Indra** Himself.

Also, since the episode has not happened at that time, most of the RigVedic verses that praise Indra's deeds of killing Vritra has not been revealed yet! So Tvashta has less verses to praise Indra.

How is it possible? Does this imply that before Rigveda there were different set of texts used to perform Yajna?

Comment: Where is mentioned it was Rig-Veda mantra. Tvastr used Atharva Veda mantras-
सुराः पश्यन्तु मे वीर्यं तपसश्च बलं तथा । 
जानातु सर्वं पापात्मा स्वकृतस्य फलं महत् ॥ ३२ ॥ 
इत्युक्त्वाग्निं जुहावाथ मन्त्रैराथर्वणोदितैः । 
पुत्रस्योत्पादनार्थाय त्वष्टा क्रोधसमाकुलः ॥ ३३॥

Comment: **Devi Puraanam, Book 6, Chapter 2**- verses 32 33. Tvastr after seeing His son VishwaRoopa dead was burning with anger and said-  **Let these Devas see my prowess and strength of my Tapas. Let this Sinful Indra know the results of his dire sinful deeds.32. Saying thus, terribly angry Tvashtr offer oblations in Fire with Mantras from Atharva Veda, to get a son.**

Comment: @AnuragSingh This should be an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "because Rigveda proceeds latter text,so I do not accept"- if it is clearly stated that Tvastr used Atharva Veda mantras, then there is no question that Rigveda mantras were used. Now if Rigveda doesn't mention it does not mean that the same story in other Scriptures is not valid.

Comment: @AnuragSingh my question was related to Rigveda mantras. As far as I understand RV precedes any other Sanskrit texts known to human kind. so I am only interested in the time where only Rigveda was composed.

Comment: @shanu okay. I understood. But, RigVeda being most ancient text is susceptible, because, all vedas are eternal and there may be possibility that all Vedas were the first one.

Comment: I do not believe that Vedas are eternal! They were composed by individuals

Answer (score 2):

It seems the myth of ' Trishira' and 'Vishvarupa' as born from the mind of 'Tvasta' has originated from RigVedic hymn RV.10.8 (8-9). On the other hand RV.1.32 (2) informs us that 'Tvasta' made 'Vajra' (thunder bolt) himself for Indra to kill Vritra, which is repeated in several other hymns of RigVeda as well. Thus the story of Purana is logically invalid : if Tvasta created Vritra to kill Indra then how he can make Vajra for Indra to kill Vritra. This kind of logical fallacy is often found in the imaginary stories. The hymns RV.10.8 (8-9) are misinterpreted and the words  from where the names Trishira (trishirsan)and Vishvarupa (vishvarupaysa) are drawn in story of Puranas  may denote something else if interpreted differently.